# How to change the star color of fyneworks API

Tags: jquery

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/star-rating/

I want to change the color of star after rating (now it's red), I want to change the color to green or yellow. How can I do that?
Thank you very much

Comment: It uses images for stars: http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/star.gif just replace them with your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is change the background image of the DIVs and As created by the plugin, like this:

```
div.star-rating, div.star-rating a{
    background-image:url('/path/to/your/green-stars.gif');
}
```

Here is an example we made:
http://jsfiddle.net/tLuqJ/1/

And here is the original image you can use as the basis to make your own colours:
http://jquery-star-rating-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/star.gif